# Calibre installations hangs

Tags: software-center

I installed Calibre via the USC, but it got to about 90% and now it only shows a message : "Waiting for configuration file prompt" It has been standing like this for 12 hours, and I can not remove it or cancel the installation.

I can't install any other apps while this is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the installation or just kill USC. After that check if Calibre works. If not, try this command on terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This yields some output on the screen. If installation is corrupted you can see this easily. After that you can try to reinstall Calibre or purge and install it again.